# ffmpg android command gives error

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am overlaying gif on video in android and using ffmpg wrapper
my command is

```
        String vidpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/vid.mp4";
        String gifpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/vid.gif";
        String outpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/out.mp4";
         ffmpeg.execProcess(new String[]{
            ffmpegBin,
            "-i",
            vidpath,
            "-i",
            gifpath,
            "-filter_complex",
            "\"overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2\"",
            //"640x388",
            out_video_path




        },sc);
```

my execProcess method is

```
 public void execProcess( String[] cmds, ShellCallback sc) throws Exception {        


        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();      

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;


        /*switch(command_call_type)
        {
        case Keys.KEY_COMMANDEXE_TYPE_MERGEFRAME:

        //  refincereference.updateLoadingbar(30);
            break;

        }*/

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (sc != null)
            {
                sc.shellOut(line.toCharArray());

            Log.e("FFMPEG", line.toCharArray()+"");


            }
        }



        /*switch(command_call_type)
        {
        case Keys.KEY_COMMANDEXE_TYPE_MERGEFRAME:

            //refincereference.updateLoadingbar(40);
            break;

        case Keys.KEY_COMMANDEXE_TYPE_CLIPMP3:
            //refincereference.updateLoadingbar(60);
            break;
        case Keys.KEY_COMMANDEXE_TYPE_MP3TOM4A:
            //refincereference.updateLoadingbar(80);
        break;

        }*/


        /*
        if (process != null) {
            process.destroy();        
        }*/

}
```

and error comes written in line object that no such file or directory
But it always gives error that gif file does not exist i have checked it wit FIle.exist() also though it gives error please help me out

Comment: What error it gives you ? Show your logcat

Comment: logcat does not shows error but whenever i check via stream object that gif file does not exist

Comment: it is not possible. there should be some.

Comment: Try to print out your gif path in logcat and check for any discrepancy in the path

Comment: I am putting edited que

Comment: if(new File(vidpath).exists()&&new File(gifpath).exists())
           com.example.utils.FFMpegVideoProcess.overlayVideo(MainActivity.this,vidpath,gifpath,outpath); and i have also checked while calling metjod

Comment: Your gifs are in Video Directory ? `String gifpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/vid.gif";` It should be in Images

Comment: /storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/vid.gif: No such file or directory

Comment: does it exists on same path ?

Comment: what make it different to put gif in video or image direcory

Comment: ya it exist so the method is called

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, I was asking to help you out. Most the time images goes into Image directory not in videos. By default Whatsapp is installed in App storage not in external storage. so check that.